# Saving value of one model field count to another field of the same model during save

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a pool app and want to add the `total_likes` attribute to the model which will allow me to count the number of users who liked the question, just like Youtube community question allows.

I just tried to override the `save(*args, **kwargs)` but got many errors.

What should I do now?

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(to=User, blank=True, related_name='voters')
    impression = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=impression_choices, blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(to=User, related_name='likes', blank=True)
    total_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.total_likes = self.likes_set.count()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The Model below works totally fine. In the model above I tried to override the `save()` method but I don't know how?

```py
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    votes = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Comment: can you share the error message you're getting?

Comment: if there is some other way to store the total counts just tell me. This error shows to me... AttributeError at /admin/pool/question/2/change/

'Question' object has no attribute 'likes_set'

Comment: Show your Post method of Question model.

Comment: my app is under production. so, I am using the django admin pannel to send a post request this time.

Comment: I am not sure whether I can use the .count inside the model or not. If that is the reason, I must have some other way to save it but don't know.

Comment: So in a custom PUT method, you can first update the like and then count total like and then update the total like.

Comment: you're using the wrong related name, your Question model is called likes to your Like model. Use Question.likes.count()